# Tesseract could not recognize text from a pdf file

Tags: python, pdf, ocr, tesseract

I tried to use `Tesseract` in `Python` to `OCR` some PDFs. The workflow is to convert a PDF to a series of images first using `wand`, then send them to `Tesseract` based on this [example](https://pythontips.com/2016/02/25/ocr-on-pdf-files-using-python/). I applied this to 5 PDFs but found it failed to convert one (completely failed). It works fine to convert PDF to Tiff. Thus, I guess maybe something needs to be tuned in the OCR process? Or any other tools I should use to deal with this situation? I tried `xpdfbin-win-3.04` which worked on this PDF but did not work as well as `Tesseract` on the other PDFs...

#### Screenshot of failed PDF

[image]

#### Output text

[image]

#### Code

from wand.image import Image
from PIL import Image as PI
import pyocr
import pyocr.builders
import io

tool = pyocr.get_available_tools()[0]
lang = tool.get_available_languages()[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5YkI.png)

pth_str = "C:/Users/TH/Desktop/OCR_test/"
fname_list = ["999437-Asb_1-34.pdf"]
for each_file in fname_list:
    print each_file
    req_image = []
    final_text = []

```
# convert to tiff
image_pdf = Image(filename=pth_str+each_file, resolution=600)
image_tif = image_pdf.convert('tiff')

for img in image_tif.sequence:
    img_page = Image(image=img)
    req_image.append(img_page.make_blob('tiff'))

# begin OCR
for img in req_image: 
    txt = tool.image_to_string(
        PI.open(io.BytesIO(img)),
        lang=lang,
        builder=pyocr.builders.TextBuilder()
    )
    final_text.append(txt.encode('ascii','ignore'))
```

Comment: Do the other PDF's you are using have similar styling (eg. font, size, italic, etc.)?

Comment: I tried different types of PDFs including scanned document, journal papers, etc.